# Django get object after save in save_model

Tags: django

it's possible get the object in function save_model after its save. For example:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
  o = super(CampaignAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

  # do something with "o"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that `save_model` does is call `obj.save()`. Therefore you can do:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    # Do something with obj
```

Or you can call `super()` if you prefer, then use `obj` afterwards.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    # this returns None so don’t assign it to anything
    super(CampaignAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    # Do something with obj
```